# How can I write output with javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, syntax, output

I have created a jsfiddle with a code that is intended to replace a string inside a paragraph with a string stored in a button. As far as I can tell, it's right. But I can't get it to work. Can someone point out my mistake?

```
<p id="arbitraryIdentification">Product information</p>
<button onclick="document.getElementByID('arbitraryIdentification').innerHTML = 'this text just replaced the original text'">text swaperizer</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q8x9oupn/1/

Comment: Case matters, it's `getElementById` ***not*** `getElementByID`

Comment: Learn to use the developer console. It would have gave you the error.

Comment: and don't put inappropriate id names in plunker

Comment: jonasnas --You mean you don't use racial slurs as place holders when you're typing quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the function `document.getElementById`.

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID; the ID is a **string** which
>   can be used to identify the element

So, your correct code would be:

```
document.getElementById('unique-key-here')
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap id in quotes and `getElementById` (not ID)

http://jsfiddle.net/q8x9oupn/3/

Answer (score 0):

1. 'getElementByID' is supposed to be '**getElementById**' ('Id' instead of 'ID')

   ```
   <button onClick="document.getElementById('arbitraryIdentification').innerHTML = 'this text just replaced the original text'">
   </button>
   ```